# Winform project migration question

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have got a few projects and when I run them on another computer, it fires an error that says: the debugging doesnt belong to...

and it opens a browser dialog box as if it wants me to point to the missing file..

How can i overcome that problem?

```
"Entering break mode failed for the following reason: Source file:"D:Document and Settings..."(path to the old directory the files were).. doesnt belong to to the project being debugged.."
```

Comment: you're using an old pdb files with your binaries, try to clear the solution and rebuild it

Comment: Right click on the solution node in the solution explorer then choose clean. or you can use the debug menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try look here:

["Entering break mode failed for the following reason: Source File XXX does not belong to the project being debugged](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/bf105e3b-2da6-4969-9fb5-50f77383f8a1/)

from the above post:

> I found 2 things that may have helped:
>
> 1)  I had previously moved the folder location of a dependent project,
>   then removed and re-added the project to my solution.  However, the
>   "References" of the depending project still showed the path to the old
>   location.  These properties are unfortunately read-only within the
>   GUI, so I just removed and re-added the project reference.
>
> 2)  I noticed that my Visual C# 2005 Express doesn't have a "Build",
>   "Clean Solution" menu option.  Instead, I closed Visual C#, deleted
>   the "bin" and "obj" directories under each project, restarted Visual
>   C#, and things are working as expected again.

Comment: In microsoft visual studio c# 2010, i cant see the option of clean solution..altho0ugh i can in Visual studio 2008

Comment: On top menu... Build > Clean solution! Otherwise you can go to your folder project and try to delete obj and bin folders